# GridView Column modification

Tags: html, asp.net, ado.net

I have bound my gridView with code behind which Contains 4 column but I want first column to be a linkbutton.
So I have added itemtemplate but now my grid contain 5 columns with two same columns, but I want only one column which is of linkbutton column.
This is my itemtemplate code

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File No">
     <ItemTemplate >
       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
         CommandArgument='<%# Eval("File") %>' Text='<%# Eval("File") %>' 
         OnCommand="show" ></asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Code behind grid binding :

```
Bussiness_logic.GridView_Bind(GridView1, "GET_DATA"); 
 public static void GridView_Bind(GridView Grid_Name,String Procdure_name)
       {
           SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(Procdure_name, GetConnection());
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           dap.Fill(ds);
           Grid_Name.DataSource = ds;
           Grid_Name.DataBind();
       }
```

Comment: I want to know how can i remove one column from grid ..since i am getting two same columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Getting five columns because you Set GridView `AutoGenerateColumn` to `true`AND add an extra template column in grid view.So `GridView` generate columns for all columns that are present in your data set and add you extra column i.e your template column.
Now to solve this issue Set `AutoGenerateColoumn` Property of GridView To `false`. Define Your Column Like below..

```
  <Columns> 
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File No">
 <ItemTemplate >
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("File") %>' Text='<%# Eval("File") %>' OnCommand="show" ></asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="NameofSecondColumnInYourDateSet" HeaderText="Column2"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="NameofThirdColumnInYourDateSet" HeaderText="Column3"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="NameofFourthColumnInYourDateSet" HeaderText="Column4"/>
    </Columns>
```

Comment: do i remove grid binding or not ??

Comment: @Ankit no need to change anything else apart from what i answered here